# Are website analytics available from Bing?

Tags: analytics, bing

Google provided a script for its analytics, using `http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` and a bunch of code they provided.

I can't seem to find something similar for Bing. I found Google Analytics right in the open, in an obvious place. I also don't see it in the MSDN library. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

Bing does not currently offer an analytics package that is the equivalent of Google Analytics.

Comment: Okay, so just to clarify, the only reason they give you an api is for the webmaster tools - which are only used to get tracking info without logging in to Bing?

Comment: Sounds about right. Google bought Urchin which made getting their analytics package up and running easy to do. I don't know if Microsoft has any interest in writing one from scratch.